# How to implement the slicing and dicing concept using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, slice, dice

I would like to understand the difference between the slicing and dicing.What is the major difference between the slicing and dicing and how to implement?Can anyone please help me to understand the concept?Thanks in Advance..Below I have written some basic code for slicing

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Country':['India', 'Australia', 'France',     'Africa','Japan','SriLanla','China'],
    'Gold':[86,32,11,2,23,21,7],'Silver':    [10,72,23,52,34,2,84],'Bronze':[8,29,36,70,32,12,1]}
Olympics = pd.DataFrame(data)

print Olympics[2:6]

print Olympics.loc[1:6]

print Olympics.iloc[1:6]
```

Comment: There's no such concept as "dicing" in `pandas` as far as I know. Where have you heard this term? Can you reference some material on this?

Comment: Are you asking the difference between [],loc and iloc? If so; iloc is very clear, you get rows(or columns) at particular positions independent of the indices. loc gets the rows(or columns) of particular index. In your example your indices are from 1 to 6 so getting 1 to 6 works. If you change how you index the data frame It won't work